VBA Looping issue
I have a problem I cant resolve in VBA.
I have all data in column A1 to A600. What I trying to do is move A1 to B1 then A2 to C1 do this for the 1st 6 cells and then on call A7 copy that to B2 for the next 6 cells and so on.
The code I have written sort of works but doesn't please see below
Thank in advance
Steve
Sub testing()
Dim k As Integer, j As Integer

For k = 1 To 6 '<~~~ Rows
For j = 4 To 9 '<~~~ Columns
        
        'Copy the cell in column A
        Cells(i).Columns("A").Copy
        'Paste to the correct cell in the column
        Cells(1).Columns(j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
Next j
Next k
End Sub


What is your excel version?

I am using Excel 365

Then you may try =WRAPROWS(A1:A100,6) or try my answer.

Please give a try to the following codes.
Sub WrapCols()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

    i = 1
    j = 2
    
    For Each rng In Range("A1:A600")
        Cells(i, j) = rng
        If j > 6 Then
            j = 2
            i = i + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub

If you want to transpose till last non empty data cell of column A then try this line
For Each rng In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


Amazing. that worked.
